# Migrating Net free C++ code written in VS 2005 to Visual C++ in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++, .net-4.0, migration

Our VB6 program currently calls code in a C++ dll. This dll does not need to be registered, it only needs a .def file specifiying the properties and methods. Vb6 late binds to it. The dll is written in VS2005 without a dependency on the Net framework.

As we are migrating our application to Net4 and also want to enhance the C++ dll with new functionality, I was wondering how to migrate the existing C++ code to VC++. I suppose thereafter the dll will just happily integrate in our solution which already contains C# and VB.Net libraries too.

Is there some tutorial/documentation about the do's and don'ts of this plan?

EDIT:
I think I have some basic misunderstanding about VC++, thinking that it can be ported to 100% managed code while keeping the C++ syntax. The replies I get seem to indicatie that VC++ will always produce native, unmanaged code?

Comment: You should edit your question since it's not clear what you mean in your comments below about keeping it functional, while removing interop. Do you think that there is some new magic in VC++ 2010 managed C++ that will remove your requirement to use interop? Perhaps you're looking for a way to rewrite the C++ DLL to use some more automated form of interop than it currently uses?

Comment: @Dabblernl, thanks for the clarification, try [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173265.aspx) as a starting point to learn about compiling C++ code for the CLR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the VS2005 project file in VS2010, VS2010 will automatically convert the old project to the new project format and the auto-conversion will do it's very best job to get everything correct.  This usually works, but not always.  So the moral of the story here is, double-check all of the new project's compiler/link settings, to be on the safe side.

Also with VS2010, you have some better interop possibilities between managed and native code:  P/Invoke and C++/CLI.  P/Invoke is simpler, but you will find that stuff may compile but fail at runtime.  C++/CLI is way more flexible, a bit more work, but makes it much easier to debug the interop, when it becomes necessary.

Comment: The whole point is that I hope to get rid of the Interop thing altogother and get a solution with C#, VB.Net and VC++ class libraries that live happily together and that can call one another's methods without any Interop measures being needed.

Comment: Well with managed and native both calling each other, you are doing interop anyway. And with VS2010 you have some better options than with 2005.

Comment: That is definitely NOT clear from your question.  You want to remove interop?

Comment: @WarrenP it seems that I am utterly clueless aboout the difference between VB.Net and C# class libraries on one side and VC++ libraries on the other. I will do some very basic reading :-)

Comment: There are lots of good ".NET + LanguageX book" questions on SO that could help you out. Good luck.  If you want to rewrite the C++ part in C#, that would remove interop, but it is possible that the DLL is in C++ for a good reason (like, that it uses an underlying C library or itself imports other unmanaged DLLs.)

Answer (score 2):

From a pure C++ point of view, you should be able to convert the VS2005 solution and project to VS2010 automatically.  If I recall when you load the solution or project into VS2010 it will automatically convert it for you.

Comment: In other words, the language changes in Visual C++ 2010 are "new features" and your source code itself, unless it has some really hairy stuff in it that was probably illegal before, shouldn't break now.  The only conversion in C++ apps that occurs is in the internals of the project-level/solution-level. I have not seen any .cpp or .hpp file modifications made as part of an import from vs 2005, to 2010.    I don't think C# and VB.net interop (using them as DLLs) has really changed that much either, mostly just the project/solution file formats.